# Session is not creating on first page load in php / Opencart

Tags: php, session, opencart

I am doing a custom work in open cart that is to detect country from IP and set store currency according to that detected country. i have done all but i have issue when i first load the website session is not create and when i refresh page session is created.

Comment: write on top of your page session_start(); also check on server session is enabled or not?

Comment: do all the things but now working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a check on session, if session is not created then force page to refresh so you can resolve this issue. I have faced similar issues and I do this to solve the problem.
You can do like this.

```
<?php 
if(isset($this->session->data['sessionName']) && $this->session->data['sessionName']=='')
    {
        echo "<script>location.reload()</script>";

    }
?>
```